# Importing a project build on Visual Studion 2005 to a solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, migrate

Here's a [project](https://github.com/CMPUT414W15TeamF/CMPUT414-Skinning) in github built in VS2005. I want to use the project in my solution in VS 2013. I downloaded the project and tried to build it with VS 2013. It gives a set of errors. Then, learning that it was built in Visual Studio 2005, I tried to build the same with VS 2010. This time the list of errors are different. Errors shown in both the cases are compile-time errors. How do I go about attacking the problem?

Errors by VS 2013:

> Error  1   error C2953: 'std::hash' : class template has already been defined  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\hashutils.h    63  1   Pinocchio
>   Error   2   error C2953: 'std::hash' : class template has already been defined  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\hashutils.h    63  1   Pinocchio
>   Error   3   error C2953: 'std::hash' : class template has already been defined  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\hashutils.h    63  1   Pinocchio
>   Error   4   error C2953: 'std::hash' : class template has already been defined  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\hashutils.h    63  1   Pinocchio
>   Error   5   error C2953: 'std::hash' : class template has already been defined  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\hashutils.h    63  1   Pinocchio
>   Warning 6   warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const double' to 'float', possible loss of data    d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\attachment.cpp 263 1   Pinocchio
>   Warning 7   warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'const double' to 'float', possible loss of data    d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\attachment.cpp 271 1   Pinocchio
>   Warning 8   warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const double' to 'float', possible loss of data    d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\attachment.cpp 359 1   Pinocchio
>   Warning 9   warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'const double' to 'float', possible loss of data    d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\attachment.cpp 364 1   Pinocchio

Errors by VS 2010:

> Error  2   error C3861: 'fminf': identifier not found  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\vec3.hpp   306 1   Pinocchio
>   Error   3   error C3861: 'fmaxf': identifier not found  d:\projectjunk\zips\cmput414-skinning-master\pinocchio\pinocchio\vec3.hpp   311 1   Pinocchio

Comment: so why are you tagging the post with `visual-studio-2012`?

Comment: VS2005 is quite old. It did not have many headers which are standard now. This means people added libraries to have those functionalities, which means you will have those definitions multple times now. Try deleting some of those, you will find the names in the error message. Also ask your teacher to provide more up-to-date projects as VS 2013 is free for educational purposes and VS2005 is not.

Comment: @Jepessen so that people who work with visual studio 2012 would also look at the problem and give it a try...

Comment: @RedX thanks for the input, I shall consider that. I think I need to make sure that the Identifiers shown in error message are defined in the manner I need in the project. Else, I need to implement them with other names. But regarding the VS2013 project, I didn't find an alternative project to meet the same requirement. The requirement is implementation of auto-rigging of a human mesh. If you know of any such projects, you may suggest it to me. Thanks.